# Android libraries - Proguard

Tags: android, security, obfuscation

I've just finished to develop an android application, so it is time to obfuscate the code, and I would like to use 'Proguard. I have edited the 'project.properties' file and I've added the line 'proguard.config=proguard.cfg'.

But my android project has dependencies with other two android projects that I have marked as android libraries.

I am not sure if the android libraries are obfuscated or if I should do anything more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those will be obfuscated as well. The obfuscator decompiles your generated jar file, obfuscates it in a new one and the obfuscated jar is then dex-ed. You need to figure out what to keep and what to obfuscate in those libraries

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand very well when you say 'You need to figure out what to keep and what to obfuscate'

Comment: Are all classes from the libraries subject to obfuscation?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure. What kind of classes should not be obfuscated? Sorry if these questions are very elementary.

Comment: What do you have in those libraries? It depends on how they're used in the project. You can proceed in obfuscating all, but later on if you see that a class needs to be kept, then you'll add specific `keep` statements in you config file.